# Look up an object by the key in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following data structure in my application:

```
var users = {
  "tom": { conversations: ["fake-uuid-v4"] },
  "bob": { conversations: ["fake-uuid-v4"] }
};

var conversations = {
  "fake-uuid-v4": {
    user_one: "tom",
    user_two: "bob"
  }
}
```

Each user has a collection of keys mapping to the conversation which contains data for the conversation, such as the last messages sent, if a user is typing, etc. The issue is I'm having a really hard time looking up the conversation.

Here's what I've tried, but it doesn't yield any results. (**Note:** I have this exact data in my firebase application right now, so this is technically a runnable example)

```
var conversation_id = 'fake-uuid-v4';
firebase.database().ref('/conversations')
    .startAt(conversation_id)
    .endAt(conversation_id)
    .on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevKey) {
        if(snapshot.val()) console.log(snapshot);
 });
```

However, it's not pulling anything from the database, if I change the code to

```
firebase.database().ref('/conversations/'+conversation_id).on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevKey) {

});
```

Then it prints out each key/value for the conversations added, in this case:

```
tom
bob
```

How can I monitor all conversations with a key that's stored in the user's conversations array?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you having trouble looping over the user's conversation ids and loading each conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick "answer" on why your first snippet won't work:

```
var conversation_id = 'fake-uuid-v4';
firebase.database().ref('/conversations')
    .startAt(conversation_id)
    .endAt(conversation_id)
    .on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevKey) {
        if(snapshot.val()) console.log(snapshot);
 });
```

You're not specifying a order, which means that the data is likely being order by priority. But I'd recommend against this approach anyway, since you're building a query, while you can directly access the child (which will be faster at scale):

```
var conversation_id = 'fake-uuid-v4';
firebase.database().ref('/conversations')
    .child(conversation_id)
    .on('child_added', function(snapshot, prevKey) {
        if(snapshot.val()) console.log(snapshot);
 });
```

Comment: The issue is that `ref(..).child(conversation_id).on('child_added'` returns each key/value pair in the object for the conversation. I need to listen to all conversations in the array. Is there not a way to have a `child_added` that returns the entire `conversation` object? for example, using `child` and `console.log(snapshot.val())` prints out `tom` and then `bob` instead of `{ user_one: 'tom', user_two: 'bob' }`

Comment: I dont want to listen to all of the conversations, because then I'll be getting data about other users conversations, so there has to be a way to only get the conversations with an id of `x`  Tl;dr, I want a child_added for the entire conversation, not just the KVP of the conversation.

Comment: `.on('value',...`?